Why IDEA does not open cloned repo?
I use IDEA 2022.1.4 Ultimate. I have faced such a problem:

I clone a repo from our corporate BB* (no matter using SSH or HTTP, I used both options).
The repo successfully clones, it copies into the IdeaProjects folder on my drive.
After that, I want to open the project structure within the IDEA, but I cannot. It doesn't open, but the start screen is opened instead of it ("Search projects" and so on).

I tried to clone another repo within the same project on BB*, and it's OK.
It seems that the problem is that repositories are placed in different projects in BB*.
What can I do to fix it?
*BB stands for Atlassian BitBucket.

It's best to contact JB support with logs.
